# multiple variables, cursor or stringarray dilemma

Tags: android, database, user-interface, cursor

i want to populate my userinterface elements with data from my database

reading the database happens over my according database class (AbezoeAdapter)

populating my userinterface is done by my mainclass (Bezoekrapporten)

now i am struggling with following code to get my idea working

```
package com.example.deceunincktechniekers;

import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.res.*;
import android.database.Cursor;

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") public class bezoekrapporten extends Activity
{
    TextView controlelijn;
    EditText scanzonedata;
String scanzonestring;
String sScan;
String Bezoeknummer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bezoekrapporten);

     //////////////////////// here is some code missing///////////////////////////


        private void vulbezoekrapportboxin(String bezoeknummer) {
    ABezoeAdapter bezoe = new ABezoeAdapter(this);

    TextView bezoekrapportnummer;
    bezoekrapportnummer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boxbrBrnum);

    TextView servicenummer;
    servicenummer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boxbrServicenum);

    TextView datum;
    datum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boxbrBrdatum);

    TextView klantnaam;
    klantnaam = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boxbrKlant);

    TextView straatnaam;
    straatnaam = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boxbrAdres);

    TextView gemeente;
    gemeente = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boxbrGemeente);

    TextView machinenummer;
    machinenummer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boxbrMachinenr);

    TextView merk;
    merk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boxbrMerk);

    TextView serienummer;
    serienummer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boxbrSerial);

    if(bezoeknummer == null)
    {
        bezoekrapportnummer.setText("-----");

    }
    else
    {
        Cursor c =bezoe.leesgegevens(bezoeknummer);

        if (c.moveToFirst()){
               while(!c.isAfterLast()){
                  String data = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("bezoekrapportdatum"));
                  controlelijn.setText(data);
                  c.moveToNext();
               }
            }
            c.close();

        bezoekrapportnummer.setText(bezoeknummer);

    }

    return;

}
```

and the code snippet from AbezoeAdapter

```
       package com.example.deceunincktechniekers;
         import android.content.ContentValues;
       import android.content.Context;
      import android.database.Cursor;
       import android.database.SQLException;
     import android.database.sqlite.*;
      import android.util.Log;

    public class ABezoeAdapter extends ADbAdapter {

public static final String recordnummer = "RECNUM";
public static final String bezoekrapportnummer = "Z01";
public static final String bezoekrapportdatum = "Z02";
public static final String herstellingsoort = "Z03";

//////////////////here is some code missing///////////////////////////:

public static final String basisservicenummer = "Z27";
public static final String verzonden = "Z28";

public static final String[] allekolommen = new String[] {bezoekrapportnummer + " AS _id", bezoekrapportdatum, 
    herstellingsoort, totaleduur, servicenummer, ONBEKEND, klantnaam, adres, machinenummer, omschrijving, 
    duur, postcode, gemeente, merk, model, serienummer, opmerkingen, werkgereed, extratijd, urenstand, gecontroleerdbureel,
    onderhoudsfiche, uitsplitsen, opmerkingbureel, ONBEKEND2, orderverwerkdatum, ordernummer, basisservicenummer, verzonden};

                //////////////////////////////here is some code missing/////////////////////////////////////////////

    public Cursor leesgegevens(String bezoeknummer) {
        open();
        Cursor c =  onzedatabase.query(true, databasetabel, allekolommen, 
                         "_id" + "=?", new String[] { bezoeknummer }, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        }
        Log.i("cursor leesgegevens", c.toString());
        sluit();
        return c;


            /////////////////////////////////////here is some code missing//////////////////
```

can anybody inform me with the best way of working to get the data from the database to my UI?

if i am already able to compile my code i get an error in my logcat that looks as follows:

```
11-24 15:58:34.089: E/AndroidRuntime(785): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 15:58:34.089: E/AndroidRuntime(785): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.deceunincktechniekers/com.example.deceunincktechniekers.bezoekrapporten}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Comment: Is the query working?  Have you set a breakpoint and looked at the values at the cursor to, at least, see if you are getting all the data? (2) Where is the first code snip from?

Comment: my problem is that bezoe.c.getcolumnindex() is not possible in eclipse, how can i find the columnindex in the class bezoekrapporten while the cursor made by the query in ABezoeAdapter?? btw: the first snippet is from bezoekrapporten

Comment: I simply define the column indexes as "public static final int".  I make sure that the definitions stay adjacent to the query so that it's easy to maintain their correspondence.

Comment: if i make public static final int brnum = allekolommen.getcolumnindex(bezoekrapportnummer) under the declaration of the allekolommen it is not working, how can i define this indexes??

Comment: I have no clue from what you are saying.  What specifically does "not working" mean?

Comment: getcolumnindex is not recognized because the cursor is not set at that point yet

Comment: Please post more segments of code so that I can see how they fit together.  If it's not too long, you can post the whole thing (but I won't read it if it's 500 or more lines).

Comment: i posted the complete related code, if you need more info, please let me know

Comment: The query looks fine.  I don't see any problems with the code you posted except that you aren't actually using the adapter.  Is your question how use the adapter and set views from the cursor?

Comment: euh, yes,..... is there an adapter for this?? how to work with it??? i was searching for such a suggestion (i think), can you show me how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did one of my adapters.  First, here's the code that does the query:

```
private void query (long uuid)
{
  // Fill list using adapter
  String cols[] = { Instances.TITLE };  // dummy field; we will set all fields together in ViewBinder
  int fields[] = { R.id.node_text };
  cursorAdapter = new CursorAdapter (this,
                                     R.layout.row_view,
                                     null, // no cursor yet
                                     cols,
                                     fields,
                                     Adapter.NO_SELECTION);
  cursorAdapter.setViewBinder (new MyViewBinder(this));

  // Setup the adapter filter - this does the query work.
  cursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider (new FilterQueryProvider()
  {
    @Override
    public Cursor runQuery (CharSequence constraint)
    {
      Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query (...your params...);
      return cursor;
    }
  });

  listView.setAdapter (cursorAdapter);
  listView.setTextFilterEnabled (true);

  // Force initial query - notice we setup an adapter with a null cursor.
  cursorAdapter.getFilter().filter (null);
}
```

Notice I did not subclass the adapter.  Instead, I subclassed ViewBinder.  Normally one lets each call to ViewBinder set one view at a time.  I thought it would be more efficient to do all the views together.  Here's how I did it:

```
private class MyViewBinder implements ViewBinder
{
  @Override
  public boolean setViewValue (View view, Cursor cursor, int column)
  {
    // Do all columns in one pass.
    if (column != SelectAndroidEvent.instancesTitleCol)
      throw new IllegalStateException ("viewbinder should only be called for title; " +
                                       "col: " + column);

    // Find encompassing layout.
    ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup)view.getParent();

    // Get fields from parentView.
    TextView titleView = (TextView)view;
    TextView field2 = (TextView)parentView.findViewById (R.id.field2);
    ...

    // set all fields together - easier.
    view.setText (cursor.getString (column);
    field2.setText (cursor.getString (FIELD2_COL);
    ...

    return true;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I give it a try in one of the next days! I will accept if everything works, thanks in advance

Comment: i still was not able to manage to make this work, what i need is something to read a complete line of data from my database with my database class, transport that data to my other class and there populate my listview with this data, any idea what the best practice is for that?

Comment: Well, that's an entirely different question.  You might try reposting it and making it more specific.  General design questions aren't appropriate in this forum and you'll need to refine it to one or more specific technical problems.

Comment: any idea what tags i shouls be searching before i can try some coding, afterwards i can make new thread for technical help with that, i have already populated my listview with pieces of my database but i now want to populate my detailfiche(xml existing of multiple textviews) with the complete datarow,(to be honnest that was the question i intended at first also)

Comment: I don't really know what tags to suggest without knowing your specific question.  There are three techniques I use for searching.  One is using google search (or whoever). The second is using the search in SO; the only tag I use is [android].  The third is to use the SO "ask question"; in this case, I prefix my "question" with android and put in a few key words; as you probably know, "ask question" displays a list of search results which you can view.  Each of these methods have their virtues and work well for different situations.